# How to test for AnonymousUser in Django Unittesting

Tags: django, testing

- I'm testing a form
- A user may be logged in, or anonymous, when presented with the form
- If the form succeeds, the user will be logged in
- If the form fails, the user will remain as they were
- I'd like to confirm this behaviour by unit testing.

`django.test.Client` does have a `login` method for this kind of thing, but given a `response` object how do I determine who is logged in?

```
    data = {'email':'john@example.com','password':'abc'}
    c = Client()
    # here was can assume `request.user` is the AnonymousUser
    # or I can use `c.login(..)` to log someone in
    r = c.post('/myform/', data)
```

Can my unittest determine who the `request.user` would now be if I were to submit a second request?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
client = Client()
# here was can assume `request.user` is the AnonymousUser
# or I can use `c.login(..)` to log someone in
from django.contrib import auth
user = auth.get_user(client) # it returns User or AnonymousUser

if user.is_anonymous():
   ...
```

It works because *client* keeps a user session (client.session).

Comment: Is there a way to do this using `RequestFactory`?

Comment: @Sebastialonso create an AnonymousUser: import with `from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser` then in your code add `request.user = AnonymousUser()`. I got this info from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777447/test-django-views-that-require-login-using-requestfactory)