# Django test RequestFactory vs Client

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am trying to decide whether I should use Django's `Client` or `RequestFactory` to test my views.

I am creating my server using DjangoRESTFramework and it's really simple, so far:

```
class SimpleModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve list of all route_areas or create a new one.
    """
    queryset = SimpleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SimpleModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (IsOwnerFilterBackend,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

What are the differences between testing with Django's `Client` and `RequestFactory` and which approach is more suited for testing a REST server (if there is any difference besides liking one better)?

Should I create tests with both so as to provide a better coverage for my system?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`RequestFactory` and `Client` have some very different use-cases. To put it in a single sentence: `RequestFactory` returns a `request`, while `Client` returns a `response`.

The `RequestFactory` does what it says - it's a factory to create `request` objects. Nothing more, nothing less.

The `Client` is used to fake a complete request-response cycle. It will create a `request` object, which it then passes through a WSGI handler. This handler resolves the url, calls the appropriate middleware, and runs the view. It then returns the response object. It has the added benefit that it gathers a lot of extra data on the `response` object that is extremely useful for testing.

The `RequestFactory` doesn't actually touch any of your code, but the `request` object can be used to test parts of your code that require a valid `request`. The `Client` runs your views, so in order to test your views, you need to use the `Client` and inspect the response. Be sure to check out [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) on the `Client`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Could you give me an example where a factory would be more appropriate to be used for testing?

Comment: If you were to create something similar to the built-in [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm), which takes a `request` object as its first argument, you'd use the `RequestFactory` to test it.

Comment: I don't think it's strictly necessary to use a `Client` to test views.  I've seen code that creates a `request` with a `RequestFactory` and then calls `SomeView.as_view()(request)` to get the response.  But I came here because I wasn't sure that's the best way to do it.  Folks in another issue say `Client` is more for integration testing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777447/test-django-views-that-require-login-using-requestfactory?rq=1

Comment: You'd use the the Request Factory if you were unit testing the View class, but you'd use the Client if you wanted to test the entire request/response cycle, for example.

Answer (score 4):

When using Django REST framework request factory would be helpfull to test the permissions.

EX:

```
Class TestPermission(TestCase):
  
    def test_admin_permisiion(self):
        admin_user = User.objects.create(email='admin@gmail.com',password='admin997',is_staff=True)
        factory = RequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/')
        request.user = admin_user
        permission = IsAdminUser()
        has_permission = permission.has_permission(request, None)
        self.assertTrue(has_permission)
```

what we have done hear is we created a admin user by setting is_staff=True , then we created a request and assigned the admin as user of the request. request factory helps us do so. then we checked the IsAdminUser() permission from DRF against the request. the test will pass .

Client is to be used when you need to test the response returned by an Api.