# django RequestFactory loses url kwargs

Tags: python, django

I am trying to switch from using Django Test Client to RequestFactory to speed up my tests. However, requests generated by RequestFactory do not supply proper `kwargs` to views.

Example: this is my view

```
class SomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({'your kwargs': str(kwargs)})
```

with urlconf

```
url(r'^some_view/(?P<some_kwarg>[\-0-9a-fA-F]+)/$',
    views.SomeView.as_view(),
    name='some_view'),
```

and two tests:

```
def test_different_kwargs():

    c = Client()
    response = c.get(
        reverse('bots:some_view',
                kwargs={'some_kwarg': '12345'}),
    )
    print('\n\nResponse for TestClient: ', response.content.decode())

    rf = RequestFactory()
    request = rf.get(
        reverse('bots:some_view',
                kwargs={'some_kwarg': '12345'}),
    )
    response = SomeView.as_view()(request)
    print('\n\nResponse for RequestFactory: ', response.content.decode())
```

What they produce is:

```
Response for TestClient:  {"your kwargs": "{'some_kwarg': '12345'}"}
Response for RequestFactory:  {"your kwargs": "{}"}
```

So, what's the point of `RequestFactory` if it loses url kwargs? Or is there a way to put them into the view somehow?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**EDIT 2020-03-07:** *As gain I more experience in testing, I updated my answer to remove confusion around functional testing and I added some advises.*

There are two aspects to your answer.

**Quick answer:** how to put the `kwargs` in the view? You need to change your code to this:

```
def test_different_kwargs():
    kwargs={'some_kwarg': '12345'}
    url = reverse('bots:some_view', kwargs=kwargs)
    c = Client()
    response = c.get(url)
    print('\n\nResponse for TestClient: ', response.content.decode())

    rf = RequestFactory()
    request = rf.get(url)
    response = SomeView.as_view()(request, **kwargs)
    print('\n\nResponse for RequestFactory: ', response.content.decode())
```

**Long answer**:
Then the difference between `RequestFactory` and `Client`:
It has been developed a bit [here: Django test RequestFactory vs Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992377/django-test-requestfactory-vs-client)
 but I would like to complete it a bit.

In terms of functionality `Client` handle the whole stack used to process the response including middlewares and url resolutions (url matching and parameters extraction). On the other side `RequestFactory`, just build a request object, leaving the responsibility to the user to add the proper attributes and to call the appropriate view functions or view methods.

Hence the call to `ClassView.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)` in the second case.

In terms of **testing**, `Client` is focused on **integration testing** (you will test that all the different parts fit together: middlewares, class-based/function view, template, templatetags), it's the end-to-end mechanism that you are testing here.

Client -> { UrlResolver -> Middleware -> View -> Middlewares -> TemplateResponse } -> Tests

Using `RequestFactory` you can focus on testing smaller parts, a class-based view method, a function view, a middleware method etc. In that sense `RequestFactory` is more related to **unit testing**.

See [Request Factory Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory)

If you are interest in unit tests and mocking methods, there is not much literature on this but you can look at this article (Testing Django Views in Isolation)[https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2015/08/02/testing-django-views-in-isolation/].

In the end it all depends on how much you time can focus on testing. Integration/Functional/Unit testings have different advantages and drawbacks.

**Advises (may be biased):** If you develop a website, I advise the following:

- focus on integration testing by testing routes and their expected behaviors ;
- add unit/integration tests for your business logic (models in Django) ;

Unit testing parts using `RequestFactory` will take you more time and won't bring much benefits over using the `Client` API.
Using `Client` API you will be closer to how your website will be used and how it will behave.