# Django test with APIRequestFactory : how to pass "flat" parameter to a view

Tags: django, url, testing, parameters, request

Django 2.2

I am writing tests for API using APIRequestFactory. The code that hits 
`/some_endpoint` and `/some_endpoint/<item_id>` already works, and so does the test that tests `/some_endpoint`. However the test to test `/some_endpoint/<item_id>` does not work because I can not find a working way to pass that `<item_id>` value to the view code. Please not it's not `/some_endpoint/<some_keyword>=<item_id>` , it's "flat" in my case i.e. there's no keyword. The problem is `<item_id>` does not make it into the view code (it's always `None` in the classview in `get_queryset` method)

I tried to pass it as `**kwargs`, it does not arrive either ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580465/django-requestfactory-loses-url-kwargs)). But that probably would not work anyway without keyword.

I tried to switch to use of Client instead of APIRequestFactory, same result. But I would rather get it working with APIRequestFactory unless it does not work this way in general. Below is the code.

test.py

```
def test_getByLongId(self) :
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    item = Item.active.get(id=1)
    print(item.longid)
    #it prints correct longid here

    request = factory.get("/item/%s" % item.longid)
    view = ItemList.as_view()
    force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
    response = view(request)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    url(item/(?P<item_id>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', views.ItemList.as_view(), name='item-detail'),
    ...
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
class ItemList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsBotOrReadOnly,)

    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

    schema = AutoSchema(
        manual_fields=[
            coreapi.Field("longid"),
        ]
    )

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned SampleSequencing to a given barcode.
        """
        longid = self.kwargs.get('item_id', None)

        print(longid)
        #prints correct longid when executed by the webserver code and prints None when executed by the test

        queryset = Item.active.filter(longid=longid)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass `item_id` into the `view()`:

```
def test_by_long_id(self) :
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    item = Item.active.get(id=1)
    print(item.longid)
    #it prints correct longid here

    request = factory.get("/item/%s" % item.longid)
    view = ItemList.as_view()
    force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
    response = view(request, item_id=item.longid)
```

or use APIClient:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

# ...
#
    def test_item_client(self):
        item = Item.active.get(id=1)
        client = APIClient()
        url = '/item/%s/' % item.id
        response = client.get(url)
```

Comment: It worked with `response = view(request, item_id=item.longid)`. I  accepted the answer. Never knew I have to pass it twice, in the urs to create request and then as kwargs to the view. Thanks!