# Django parameters in URL

Tags: django, testing, url, django-rest-framework, parameters

I am trying to write a delete function for my CRUD API with Python Rest Framework. In the delete I want to delete a specific item in the database, and I want it to be passed via link parameter like so: `path/to/link/to/delete/post3.`

I did that in the url file:

```
path("link/<int:link_pk>/", views.LinkView.as_view(),
         name="link_integration")
```

Then, in the ApiView that is the code:

```
    @log_request_decorator
    def delete(self, request: Request, link_pk: int, **kwargs) -> JsonResponse:
        do_stuff()
        #print(social_integration_pk)
        return JsonResponse({}, status=204)
```

And here is the code of the test that I am using to test it:

```
link = "link/1/"
factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.delete(link)
view = LinkView.as_view()
---forced auth---
response = view(request)
```

And I get this as output:

```
TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'link_pk'
```

Do someone know how to fix that? I need to have that parameter in order to do what I am supposed to. Maybe is something silly, but I don't know. If you can, please help me. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django test with APIRequestFactory : how to pass "flat" parameter to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560504/django-test-with-apirequestfactory-how-to-pass-flat-parameter-to-a-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion that it could be one of two things:

1. `response = view(request)` should be `response = view(request, link_id=1)` OR
2. `view = LinkView.as_view()` should be `view = LinkView.as_view({'delete':'delete'})`